# Use Google's voice recognition as a Windows 10 dictation engine

Tags: windows-10, google-drive

I'm using a Windows 10 build 1909 desktop system.

The Windows 10 dictation feature is terrible at spelling things wrong and misunderstanding what I'm staying. For example, it interprets "PowerShell" as "power shell" and it doesn't understand common acronyms like "AWS."

Conversely, the built-in dictation feature in Google Drive / Docs is absolutely amazing, with 90%+ accuracy. I'm wondering if there's a way to use Google's voice recognition engine as a replacement for the Windows 10 dictation engine, so I can dictate text into any Windows application or webpage in Google Chrome.

**Question**: Can I use Google's voice recognition as a generic input device on the Windows 10 operating system?